# My react-dates DateRangePicker is not working/rendering when clicked

Tags: reactjs, redux, momentjs, react-dates

I'm building a react redux expense tracking app and use moment.js and react-dates to set time and filter time range. However I am getting the error when I select anywhere, or the "x" to clear date, then nothing renders to screen.

```
expenses.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at expenses.js:9
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at expenses.js:5
    at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (ExpenseList.js:17)
    at mapToPropsProxy (wrapMapToProps.js:41)
    at handleNewState (selectorFactory.js:44)
    at handleSubsequentCalls (selectorFactory.js:58)
    at pureFinalPropsSelector (selectorFactory.js:63)
    at Subscription.checkForUpdates [as onStateChange] (connectAdvanced.js:247)
    at Subscription.handleChangeWrapper (Subscription.js:70)
```

I have double checked and still couldn't find what's wrong...

reducers/filters:

```
const filterReducerDefaultState = {
    text: '',
    sortBy: 'date',
    startDate: moment().startOf('month'),
    endDate: moment().endOf('month')
}
```

Here is the selectors/expenses.js:

```
import moment from 'moment'

//Get visible expenses
export default (expenses, { text, sortBy, startDate, endDate }) => {
    return expenses.filter((expense) => {
        const createdAtMoment = moment(expense.createdAt)
        const startDateMatch = startDate ? startDate.isSameOrBefore(createdAtMoment, 'day') : true
        const endDateMatch = endDate? endDate.isSameOrAfter(createdAtMoment, 'day'): true
        const textMatch = expense.description.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())

        return startDateMatch && endDateMatch && textMatch
    }).sort((a, b) => {
        if (sortBy === 'date') {
            return a.createdAt < b.createdAt ? 1 : -1
        } else if (sortBy === 'amount') {
            return a.amount < b.amount ?  1 : -1
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the components/ExpenseListFilters.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates'
import { setTextFilter, sortByAmount, sortByDate, setStartDate, setEndDate } from '../actions/filters'

class ExpenseListFilters extends React.Component{
    state={
        calendarFocused: null
    }
    onDatesChange = ({startDate, endDate}) => {
        this.props.dispatch(setStartDate(startDate))
        this.props.dispatch(setEndDate(endDate))
    }
    onFocusChange = (calendarFocused) => {
        this.setState(() => ({ calendarFocused}))
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
        <input 
        type="text" 
        value={this.props.filters.text} 
        onChange={(e) => {
            this.props.dispatch(setTextFilter(e.target.value))
        }} />
        <select 
        value ={this.props.filters.sortBy}
        onChange={(e)=> {
            if (e.target.value === 'date'){
                this.props.dispatch(sortByDate())
            } else if (e.target.value === 'amount') {
                this.props.dispatch(sortByAmount())
            }
        }}>
            <option value="date">Date</option>
            <option value="amount">Amount</option>
        </select>
        <DateRangePicker 
        startDate={this.props.filters.startDate}
        startDateId='startDateId'
        endDate={this.props.filters.endDate}
        endDateId='endDateId'
        onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
        focusedInput={this.state.calendarFocused}
        onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
        showClearDates={true}
        numberOfMonths={1}
        isOutsideRange={()=> false}
        />
    </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        filters: state.filters
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExpenseListFilters)
```

I expect to be able to clear the date by clicking "X" on calender so my demo data can show up, or select certain range to filter.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I solved my problem now: I forget to include ...state in my reducers/filters in the :

```
        case 'SET_START_DATE':
            return {
                startDate: action.startDate
            }
        case 'SET_END_DATE':
            return {
                endDate: action.endDate
            }
```

and it should be:

```
        case 'SET_START_DATE':
            return {
                ...state,
                startDate: action.startDate
            }
        case 'SET_END_DATE':
            return {
                ...state,
                endDate: action.endDate
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the error reads `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`, your problem is in the code `const textMatch = expense.description.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())`

To prevent problems like this, I like to include a default value which could look as follows

```
export default (expenses, { text = '', sortBy, startDate, endDate }) => {
    return expenses.filter((expense = {}) => {
        const { description = '' } = expense
        const createdAtMoment = moment(expense.createdAt)
        const startDateMatch = startDate ? startDate.isSameOrBefore(createdAtMoment, 'day') : true
        const endDateMatch = endDate? endDate.isSameOrAfter(createdAtMoment, 'day'): true
        const textMatch = expense.description.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())

        return startDateMatch && endDateMatch && textMatch
    }).sort((a, b) => {
```

By adding a default value to text, expense, and description your code won't error out - but the problem will likely not be solved.

To solve the problem I'd recommend adding console logs to every line to ensure that the values match what you expect them to be - or use nodejs's built in `debugger` tool